# Can you stack the benefits of the teamwork feats Coordinated Shot and Enfilading Fire?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, flanking

[Teamwork Feats](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/teamwork-feats) in the Feat Description says

> **Benefit**: What the feat enables the character (“you” in the feat description) to do. If a character has the same feat more than once, its benefits do not stack unless indicated otherwise in the description.

If my ally has the feat [Coordinated Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/coordinated-shot-combat-teamwork) and I have the feat [Enfilading Fire](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/enfilading-fire-combat-teamwork) do the benefits stack for a +4 bonus on attack rolls if my ally is flanking?

If so and I'm within 30 feet, does the feat [Point Blank Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/point-blank-shot-combat-final/) make the bonus on attack rolls +5?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, their bonuses stack.

Both feats grant *untyped* bonuses, and those generally stack if they are not from the same source (such as having the same feat twice).

The situation for both of those to stack, however, is *very specific* and difficult to happen from my personal experience.

- Your target must be flanked by at least two allies.
- None of them can be anywhere between your target and you (cover).
- One of which must either have both teamwork feats **or** each ally must have one of the two feats (unless you happen to have [solo tactics](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor#TOC-Solo-Tactics-Ex-)).

Comment: Only one of the two teammates needs Coordinated Shot. The bonus increases if your teammate is flanking, whether the flanker has the feat or not (it's called out in the feat). One ally with both feats or two allies with one of them each give equal bonuses.

Comment: @Delioth my error is actually regarding Enfilading Fire, not Coordinated Shot. Only one ally has to own both feats, the other doesn't matter, **or**, each ally must have one of the two feats.

Comment: @ShadowKras my thoughts were to take both feats and use [tactican](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/cavalier/#TOC-Tactician-Ex-) to give allies Coordinated Shot

Answer (score 0):

If your ally, who is flanking, has Coordinated shot and you have Enfilading fire nothing happens. The reason is that teamwork feats only work if two creatures, which are working together, both have the same teamwork feat.

If both, you and your ally have both feats you get +3 on the ranged attack roll. +4 if the creature flanking with your ally is an ally of you, too.